# Determine if dates are continuous in a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe containing the id of some person and the date on which he performed a certain action:

```
+----+----------+
|  id|      date|
+----+----------+
|   1|2022-09-01|
|   1|2022-10-01|
|   1|2022-11-01|
|   2|2022-07-01|
|   2|2022-10-01|
|   2|2022-11-01|
|   3|2022-09-01|
|   3|2022-10-01|
|   3|2022-11-01|
+----+----------+
```

I need to determine the fact that this person performed some action over a certain period of time (suppose the last 3 months). In a specific example, person number 2 missed months 08 and 09, respectively, the condition was not met. So I expect to get the following result:

```
+----+------------------------------------+------+
|  id|                               dates|3month|
+----+------------------------------------+------+
|   1|[2022-09-01, 2022-10-01, 2022-11-01]|  true|
|   2|[2022-07-01, 2022-10-01, 2022-11-01]| false|
|   3|[2022-09-01, 2022-10-01, 2022-11-01]|  true|
+----+------------------------------------+------+
```

I understand that I should group by person ID and get an array of dates that correspond to it.

```
data.groupBy(col("id")).agg(collect_list("date") as "dates").withColumn("3month", ???)
```

However, I'm at a loss in writing a function that would carry out a check for compliance with the requirement.I have an option using recursion, but it does not suit me due to low performance (there may be more than one thousand dates). I would be very grateful if someone could help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple trick is to use a `set` instead of a `list` in your aggregation, in order to have distinct values, and then check the size of that set.
Here are some possible solutions:

##### Solution 1

Assuming you have a list of months of interest on which you want to check, you can perform a preliminary filter on the required months, then aggregate and validate.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
import java.time.{LocalDate, Duration}

val requiredMonths = Seq(
    LocalDate.parse("2022-09-01"),
    LocalDate.parse("2022-10-01"),
    LocalDate.parse("2022-11-01")
);

df
    .filter(F.date_trunc("month", $"date").isInCollection(requiredMonths))
    .groupBy($"id")
    .agg(F.collect_set(F.date_trunc("month", $"date")) as "months")
    .withColumn("is_valid", F.size($"months") === requiredMonths.size)
```

`date_trunc` is used to truncate the `date` column to month.

##### Solution 2

Similar to the previous one, with preliminary filter, but here assuming you have a range of months

```scala
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

val firstMonth = LocalDate.parse("2022-09-01");
val lastMonth = LocalDate.parse("2022-11-01");

val requiredNumberOfMonths = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(firstMonth, lastMonth) + 1;

df
  .withColumn("month", F.date_trunc("month", $"date"))
  .filter($"month" >= firstMonth && $"month" <= lastMonth)
  .groupBy($"id")
  .agg(F.collect_set($"month") as "months")
  .withColumn("is_valid", F.size($"months") === requiredNumberOfMonths)
```

##### Solution 3

Both *solution 1* and *2* have a problem that causes the complete exclusion from the final result of the `id`s that have no intersection with the dates of interest.
This is caused by the filter applied before grouping.

Here is a solution based on *solution 2* that does not filter and solves this problem.

```scala
df
   .withColumn("month", F.date_trunc("month", $"date"))
   .groupBy($"id")
   .agg(F.collect_set(F.when($"month" >= firstMonth && $"month" <= lastMonth, $"month")) as "months")
   .withColumn("is_valid", F.size($"months") === requiredNumberOfMonths)
```

Now the filter is performed using a conditional `collect_set`.

It is right to consider also *solution 1* and *2* because the preliminary filter can have advantages and in some cases that could be the expected result.